# Make an intent start after a preset amount of time

Tags: android, android-intent

I want a new activity to be started via an `intent` after a preset amount of time of inactivity has passed. I used the code pasted below but it still does not work and it stays on the same screen. I know this is not the android-y way to do it, but I'm pretty sure it should work (it makes more sense to me this way). On a side note, could I use this to make something like a textview, button or other object change its visibility from `invisible` to `visible`? I've looked around and haven't found any answers. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Welcome extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //do stuff
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Welcome.this,MainActivity.class);
                    Welcome.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: **"I know this is not the android-y way to do it"** - So why are you trying to do it then? Also, if I'm using an `Activity` in an app and get distracted for 10 seconds (for whatever reason) when I come back to a totally different `Activity` how am I going to feel? It's a bad user experience.

Comment: It's just a test project, so I can get better acquainted with android in case I need to use it for a real application. I'm familiar with Java and it's logic so I did it more that way since Android's SDK is built on top of it. I don't know the correct way to do it on Android and I did research before asking. Thanks for the tip about UX though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a thread and make it sleep for that interval of time. After that time your new intent will be started.

Eg:-

```
Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       try {
                           int waited = 0;
                           while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                               sleep(100);
                               if(_active) {
                                   waited += 100;
                               }
                           }
                       } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                           // do nothing
                       } finally {
                           finish();

                          Intent intent = new Intent(First_Intent.this,Second_Intent.class );
                            startActivity(intent);
                       }
                   }
               };
               splashTread.start();


               }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with a handler :

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(<your runnable>, delayInMillis);
```

For updating widgets, it's not a very good idea to do it that way. You would be better using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if the delay is not very large.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Do your thing......

             Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 3000);
```